# Zip function not working properly on server

Tags: php, zip

Any ideas on why this is perfectly working in my localhost but not in the server where I uploaded it to? In the server, it creates the zip but does not create the folders, it puts all the files inside the .zip, with no folders distinction.

```
function rzip($source, $destination) {
    // create object
    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    // open archive
    if ($zip->open($destination, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE) !== TRUE) {
        die ("Could not open archive");
    }

    $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($source));
    foreach ($iterator as $key=>$value) {
        $new_filename = substr($key,strrpos($key,"/") + 1);
        $zip->addFile(realpath($key), $new_filename) or die ("ERROR: Could not add file: $key");
    }

    $zip->close();
}
```

Comment: I have no clue why it works on your localhost, but you're just adding the basename of each file into the zip. How should the zip know about to which folder inside the zip that file should belong to?

Comment: You should check your Servers Error-logs for some hint. Also you should check, if the php-version of your server and your localhost match. Edit those things to your question.

Comment: @luqita: You're using realpath for the file. That's fine. But what counts is the second parameter, localpath. It's in the docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ziparchive-addfile.php - you should add the directory that you want to have in the zip archive as well next to the basename otherwise all files in your zip appear as being in one folder.

Comment: The `realpath()` only deals with the location of the source file, not where it ends up in the zip file. There are also a number of problems with your usage (or lack thereof) of the `RecursiveDirectoryIterator`'s features, which is making life more difficult in your script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mis-using (or not using) the `RecursiveDirectoryIterator` in places.

The first point is that you will iterate over the dot folders (`.` and `..`) which is probably undesired; to stop this, use the `SKIP_DOTS` flag.

Next, there are tools to get the file's path relative to the main directory being iterated over and to get the *real path* too; using the `getSubPathname()` and `getRealpath()` methods, respectively.

```
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator(
                $source, RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS));
foreach ($iterator as $key => $value) {
    $localname = $iterator->getSubPathname();
    $filename  = $value->getRealpath();
    $zip->addFile($filename, $localname) or die ("ERROR: Could not add file: $key");
}
```

The above is only an answer because it's too long for a comment. Nothing above answers why, "*this is perfectly working in my localhost but not in the server*".

Comment: Made it like this: $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator(
                $source));
  foreach ($iterator as $key => $value) {
     $localname = $iterator->getSubPathname();
     $filename  = $value->getRealpath();
     $zip->addFile($filename, $localname) or die ("ERROR: Could not add file: $key");
  }